# jQuery - find if a child input element is checked without referencing its id explicitly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the code below it displays two check-boxes and I want to find if the first input (or checkbox) has the 'checked' attribute set to true.

```
<ul id="checklist">
    <li id="box1">
        <label>
            <input id="box_input" type="checkbox"> "A CheckBox" </label>
    </li>
    <li id="box2">
        <label>
            <input id="box_input_2" type="checkbox"> "Another CheckBox"</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Without referencing the id of the first checkbox how can I get jQuery to see if the first list item is checked?

ex below:

```
$('#checklist).child('li label first:input').is(':checked');
```

Comment: `$('#checklist).find("(input:checked):first");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check :

```
$("#checklist :checkbox:first:checked").length>0
```

Optimization :

To prevent jQuery search `*` items , and find only input type ,  , this should be made :

```
$("#checklist input:checkbox:first:checked").length>0
```

From jQuery :

> it is recommended to precede it with a tag name or some other
>   selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("*") is implied. In other
>   words, the bare `$(':checkbox')` is equivalent to `$( "*:checkbox" )`, so
>   $( "input:checkbox" ) should be used instead.

Comment: input:checkbox should be used to avoid * selector.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var res = $("#checklist input:eq(0)").is(function() {
  return this.checked
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "checklist">
     <li id = "box1">
      <label> <input id = "box_input" type = "checkbox"> "A CheckBox"  </label>
     </li>
      <li id = "box2">
      <label> <input id = "box_input_2" type = "checkbox"> "Another CheckBox"</label>
     </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO get the first checked checkbox**

1. Use `find` because `checkbox` is not the direct child of `ul#checklist`
2. Use `:checkbox` pseudo-selector to get all checkboxes
3. Use `first` to get first checkbox
4. Use `is(':checked')` to get the checked status

   `$('#checklist').find(':checkbox').first().is(':checked');`

**OR**

```
$('#checklist :checkbox:first').is(':checked');
```

Comment: this will check the first checkbox  that is checked . not the first checkbox to be checked !

Comment: yes but now , there are too many function executed just to find it....(find , first , is)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Shortened!